# How can I run a exchange powershell command with different credentials through Node.js?

Tags: node.js, powershell

**Context:**

I'm creating a Electron React Application. I'm building it for my colleagues. 
This app will give you a simple to use UI. You can do different things for which you normally would need powershell.
Example: Gui asks you for a user you want to access and another user that it should grant access too.

I'm then passing everything we need to powershell-node (a package that handles powershell with node) and it will (in this example) grant Full Access Permissions to the user specified.

**The Problem**

We are using a different account to fire exchange and powershell commands since we don't have rights with our personal logon. So normally I would create a pssession to our ex server like this:

```
$Connection = @{
ConfigurationName = 'Microsoft.Exchange' 
ConnectionUri     = 'http://ourserver/powershell' 
Authentication    = 'Kerberos' 
Credential        = Get-Credential}

$Ex2010Session = New-PSSession @Connection
Import-PSSession $Ex2010Session -AllowClobber | Out-Null
```

Normally this would work and give me the commandlet `add-mailboxpermission`.
Also the command itself works on a normal powershell because I open it with my Admin account (run as). And that's the point:

In my script I do exactly this but then afterwards I run the `Add-Mailboxpermission` command with all required parameters.

Of course it won't work because I opened my electron app with my normal account. Also there is not `-Credential` parameter on the `Add-MailboxPermission` command.

**A possible solution;**
The first idea that comes into my mind is, to just open the app with the adm account. While possible I'm aspire for a better solution.

**What have I tried**

The next idea I got is "Why don't I just send the command to the server via invoke-command like this:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Ex2010Session -ScriptBlock {
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $Identity -AccessRights 'FullAccess' -user 
$User -automapping $Automapping
}
```

Unfortunately when I try to run this I get this error message:

> variable that cannot be referenced in restricted language mode or a Data section is being referenced. Variables that 
>   can be referenced include the following: $PSCulture, $PSUICulture, $true, $false, and  $null.

I don't have any access to our ex infrastructure and therefore can't try to fix it on these side of problems (language mode).

So there I am, having no idea how to solve this problem. I hope you guys have any ideas how to fix it, that would be very neat.

Little Screenshot of the app:
[image]